# Linear Programming Problem Exercise.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-programming, operations-research

A firm has to transport $1200$ packages using large vans which can carry $200$ packages each and small vans which can take $80$ packages each.The cost for engaging each large van is Rs $ 400$ and each small van is Rs $200$.Not more than Rs $3000$ is to be spent on the job and the number of large vans cannot exceed the number of small vans.Formulate this problem as a LPP given that the objective is to minimize cost.

[Here](http://clay6.com/qa/2618/a-firm-has-to-transport-1200-packages-using-large-vans-which-can-carry-200-) the solution is also given. But I am not understanding why is the restriction for cost (2nd restriction) $400x+200y≥3000$ ? It seems to me $400x+200y\le3000$ is appropriate. Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  $400x + 200 y \leq 3000$ is the correct inequality.

Comment: I have edited $y$ in the correct inequality. One more question:  Is the $200x+80y≥1200$ inequality correct. I think yes. But a little bit confused.

Comment: @time : You could have made that question part of your original post...  Since the $x$ large vans and $y$ small vans carry $200x+80y$ packages and they must carry at least $1200$ packages, that inequality is correct.

Comment: You have a typo. It is $400x+200y\leq 3000$

Comment: @calculus : True.  Now it and the one in the OP are fixed.